# Component Alignment Issues and Components Don't Show

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I have been trying to use [react-native-avataaars](https://github.com/tom555my/react-native-avataaars/issues/9) for a few days. It's not a maintained package so I ended up taking the two main files (`index.js` and `index.json`) and just adding them to my project to fix any issues. I finally got the `Avatar` component working, but it has alignment issues. Even when I style it to be centered, the `Avatar` is shifted to the left.

I am also trying to show a popup that displays an `Avatar` along with all of the options to customize it. For the options I tried to use `Piece` components in a `ScrollView` but that resulted in no options showing. It works when I just try one specific piece. At the same time a bunch of warnings are logged, saying `WARN  Webview Process Terminated` which tells me the components are there, they are just being terminated. How can I fix this?

Package `index.js`:

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
    __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
            s = arguments[i];
            for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
                t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
    };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
};
import * as React from "react";
import { PixelRatio } from "react-native";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import Image from "react-native-remote-svg";
import { default as AvatarReact, Piece as PieceReact } from "avataaars";
var Avatar = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Avatar, _super);
    function Avatar() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    Avatar.prototype.render = function () {
        var size = this.props.size;
        return (React.createElement(Image, { source: {
                uri: "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(AvatarReact, __assign({ style: {
                        width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(size),
                        height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(size)
                    } }, this.props)))
            }, style: {
                width: size,
                height: size
            } }));
    };
    return Avatar;
}(React.Component));
export { Avatar };
var Piece = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Piece, _super);
    function Piece() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    Piece.prototype.render = function () {
        var pieceSize = this.props.pieceSize;
        return (React.createElement(Image, { source: {
                uri: "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(PieceReact, __assign({}, this.props)))
            }, style: {
                width: Number(pieceSize),
                height: Number(pieceSize)
            } }));
    };
    return Piece;
}(React.Component));
export { Piece };
```

Package `index.ts`:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { PixelRatio, View } from "react-native";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
// @ts-expect-error
import Image from "react-native-remote-svg";
import { default as AvatarReact, Piece as PieceReact } from "avataaars";

export interface Props {
  avatarStyle: string;
  size: number;
  topType?: string;
  accessoriesType?: string;
  hairColor?: string;
  facialHairType?: string;
  facialHairColor?: string;
  clotheType?: string;
  clotheColor?: string;
  graphicType?: string;
  eyeType?: string;
  eyebrowType?: string;
  mouthType?: string;
  skinColor?: string;
  pieceType?: string;
  pieceSize?: string;
}

export interface PieceProps {
  avatarStyle: string;
  topType?: string;
  accessoriesType?: string;
  hairColor?: string;
  facialHairType?: string;
  facialHairColor?: string;
  clotheType?: string;
  clotheColor?: string;
  graphicType?: string;
  eyeType?: string;
  eyebrowType?: string;
  mouthType?: string;
  skinColor?: string;
  pieceType?: string;
  pieceSize?: string;
}

export class Avatar extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { size } = this.props;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: size,
          height: size,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
              <AvatarReact
                style={{
                  width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(size),
                  height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(size),
                }}
                {...this.props}
              />
            )}`,
          }}
          style={{
            width: size,
            height: size,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class Piece extends React.Component<PieceProps> {
  render() {
    const { pieceSize } = this.props;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: Number(pieceSize),
          height: Number(pieceSize),
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
              <PieceReact {...this.props} />
            )}`,
          }}
          style={{
            width: Number(pieceSize),
            height: Number(pieceSize),
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Usage in project:

```js
      <AwesomeAlert
        show={showAlert}
        showProgress={false}
        title="Edit Avatar"
        closeOnTouchOutside={true}
        closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
        showCancelButton={true}
        showConfirmButton={true}
        customView={
          <>
            <View
              style={{
                width: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.8,
                // flexDirection: "row",
                // justifyContent: "space-between",
              }}
            >
              <View style={styles.avatarWrapper}>
                <Avatar
                  size={150}
                  avatarStyle="Circle"
                  topType={avatarStyle.topType}
                  accessoriesType={avatarStyle.accessoriesType}
                  hairColor={avatarStyle.hairColor}
                  facialHairType={avatarStyle.facialHairType}
                  clotheType={avatarStyle.clotheType}
                  eyeType={avatarStyle.eyeType}
                  eyebrowType={avatarStyle.eyebrowType}
                  mouthType={avatarStyle.mouthType}
                  skinColor={avatarStyle.skinColor}
                />
              </View>
              <ScrollView
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: "flex-start" }}
                horizontal={true}
              >
                <Piece
                  pieceType="top"
                  pieceSize="40"
                  topType={"Turban"}
                  avatarStyle=""
                />
                {topTypes.map((item) => (
                  <Piece
                    key={item}
                    pieceType="top"
                    pieceSize="40"
                    topType={item}
                    avatarStyle=""
                  />
                ))}
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          </>
        }
        cancelText="Cancel"
        confirmText="Save"
        confirmButtonColor="#DD6B55"
        onCancelPressed={() => {
          setShowAlert(false);
        }}
        onConfirmPressed={() => {
          setShowAlert(false);
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know where the `WebView` component was coming from but that was the source of the issue. I saw that a package called `react-native-remote-svg` was being used and assumed that was where the `WebView` was, so I tried `react-native-svg` and everything worked. Not only can I see the components now, but the alignment is correct too.